# Error while accessing WCF serivce hosted on local IIS: "This operation is not supported for a relative URI."

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis, .net-4.0

I am getting "**This operation is not supported for a relative URI.**" error while accessing WCF service from my web-browser. The service is hosted on local IIS and following is its configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <!-- change -->
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="Wrabind" closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" sendTimeout="00:25:00">
          <textMessageEncoding/>
          <security authenticationMode="SecureConversation" includeTimestamp="true" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
            <localClientSettings maxClockSkew="00:30:00" />
            <localServiceSettings maxClockSkew="00:30:00" />
            <secureConversationBootstrap messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
              <localClientSettings maxClockSkew="00:30:00" />
              <localServiceSettings maxClockSkew="00:30:00" />
            </secureConversationBootstrap>
          </security>
          <httpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" allowCookies="true" maxBufferSize="20000000" keepAliveEnabled="false" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
<services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="wrCoreService.Service1Behavior" name="wrCoreService.Service1">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/service1.svc" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="Wrabind" contract="wrCoreService.IService1" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="wrCoreService.Service1Behavior">
          <serviceThrottling
maxConcurrentCalls="200"
maxConcurrentSessions="200"
maxConcurrentInstances="200" />
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <!-- change -->
          <!--<serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="wrCoreService.Authentication.DistributorValidator, wrCoreService"/>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="wrCoreService" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="TrustedPeople" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
          </serviceCredentials>-->
          <!-- change -->
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />

        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment>
      <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
        <add prefix="localhost/" />
      </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <!--<standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true"
          automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>-->

  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

As error explains you can only have absolute URI not relative. try to give absolute URI instead of `localhost/`

```
<baseAddressPrefixFilters>
  <add prefix="localhost/" />
</baseAddressPrefixFilters>
```

Comment: so what will be the absolute URI for localhost? Because I tried `localhost` , `localhost:80\` but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

`<serviceHostingEnvironment>`
`<baseAddressPrefixFilters>`
`<add prefix="http://localhost/" />`
`</baseAddressPrefixFilters>`
`</serviceHostingEnvironment>`

Comment: Nope, already tried that its not working. Its showing `Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding MetadataExchangeHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [].` exception.

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva In the endpoint you mentioned bindingconfiguration as "Wrabind", but in your configuration I don't see any binding configuration related to "Wrabind". Post your configuration info completely.

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva : how are you creating the custom binding is through code or through configuration file ?? Do mention the complete information, or else none of them can answer your question by giving half information.

Comment: ok I think now its clear that I am using configuration file to create bindings. So how can I solve my problem in this situation?

Comment: If you are using configuration file to create custom bindings, then there should be <extensions> <bindingExtensions> entry in your configuration file, I don't see any entry in your config file. Those are entries are required or else it will not recognize your custom binding.

Comment: I don't think missing of this element can have some effect. But I tried and added the element like this `<extensions>
        <bindingExtensions>
           <add name="Wrabind" type="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.MyBinding, MyBinding,
                Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
        </bindingExtensions>
    </extensions>` 
but no effect. The same error is coming.

Answer (score 0):

As Abhinay said, you need the `http://` in the prefix in order for it to be a fully qualified URI (which requires a scheme).  So I'd say try:

`http://localhost` (no trailing slash)

or

`http://127.0.0.1`

or

`http://your-machine-name.domain.whatever`

Also try including the port number (e.g. `http://localhost:8080`) if you are on a nonstandard port.

Lastly, your endpoint tag may actually *require* a relative path for its address (I have seen that before), so:

```xml
<service behaviorConfiguration="wrCoreService.Service1Behavior" name="wrCoreService.Service1">
    <endpoint address="service1.svc" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="Wrabind" contract="wrCoreService.IService1" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
</service>
```

Comment: not working. Its showing the same error or `Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding MetadataExchangeHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [].`

Answer (score 0):

baseAddressPrefixFilters does not recognize “localhost”, use the fully qualified machine name instead.

Here's the [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924481.aspx).